# How to make LESS 'remember' search patterns after I close it?

Tags: linux

Once I had LESS that 'remembered' all search patterns.
After I made searches in one file, closed it and then opened another file, all search history was there.
Now I don't have this feature: if I have to search certain string in multiple files, I have to type the string in every file.
How to enable search history preservation?

Comment: Removed the Less tag as the question doesn't seem to be about the Less CSS pre-processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the environement variable `LESSHISTFILE`. Check [`man less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less), section `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`.